# 1 Regexp на 2 разных типа событий с одного устройства

Tags: регулярные-выражения, логирование

Есть 3 вида событий:

```
1) <134> 01/11/1990:13:26:00 GMT 1234SERVER1 0-PPE-0 : default TCP CONN_TERMINATE 23168132 0 :  Source 1.1.1.1:8888 - Destination 1.1.1.2:9999 - Start Time 01/11/1990:13:25:18 GMT - End Time 01/11/1990:13:26:00 GMT - Total_bytes_send 1 - Total_bytes_recv 1
2) <134> 01/11/1990:13:26:00 GMT 1234SERVER1 0-PPE-0 : default TCP CONN_DELINK 23168133 0 :  Source 1.1.1.4:8888 - Vserver 1.1.1.6:22 - NatIP 1.1.1.5:60002 - Destination 10.1.1.9:22 - Delink Time 01/11/1990:13:26:00 GMT - Total_bytes_send 2334 - Total_bytes_recv 3174
3) <135> 01/11/1990:13:26:03 GMT 1234SERVER1 0-PPE-0 : default SSLLOG SSL_HANDSHAKE_SUCCESS 23168136 0 :  SPCBId 2592498 - ClientIP 192.168.121.132 - ClientPort 56468 - VserverServiceIP 1.1.1.12 - VserverServicePort 443 - ClientVersion TLSv1.2 - CipherSuite "AES-256-CBC-SHA TLSv1.2 Non-Export 256-bit" - Session New
```

Написал Regexp под событие №1 (разбирает полностью и как нужно), и столкнулся с проблемой - не могу дописать его таким образом, чтобы этот Regexp разбирал все 3 события.
Можно ли это как-то сделать? В идеале, мне нужно выхватывать из всех событий только:

```
Время (01/11/1990:13:26:00);
Устройство (1234SERVER1);
Событие (TCP CONN_TERMINATE/TCP CONN_DELINK/SSLLOG SSL_HANDSHAKE_SUCCESS);
Source и Destination IP:Port (Source 1.1.1.1:8888 - Destination 1.1.1.2:9999);
Еще раз Время (Start Time 01/11/1990:13:25:18 GMT - End Time 01/11/1990:13:26:00 - но не обязательно)
```

Конкретно проблема с тем, что, например, в событии №2 после Source IP идет VServer и NatIP, которого нет в событии №1. Или, если смотреть дальше, в том же событии №2, после Destination IP идет Delink Time, а в событии №1 Start Time + End Time. В событии №3 затык перед SPCBId и в дальнейшем перед VserverServiceIP/Port и т.д.
Буду благодарен за советы/варианты решения моей проблемы.
Спасибо.

Написанный мной Regex:

```
<(\d+)> (\d+\/\d+\/\d+\d\d:\d\d:\d\d:\d+) GMT (\d+\S+) 0-PPE-0 : default (\S+ \S+) (\d+) (\d+) :  Source (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+):(\d+) \- Destination (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+):(\d+) \- (\w*) Time (\d+\/\d+\/\d+\d\d:\d\d:\d\d:\d+) GMT \- End Time (\d+\/\d+\/\d+\d\d:\d\d:\d\d:\d+) GMT \- Total_bytes_send (\d+) \- Total_bytes_recv (\d+)
```

Comment: зачем так сложно даты расписывать, например? у вас там может быть не дата по факту? `([\d:\/]+)` не достаточно чтоб выцепить дату целиком, зачем портянки эти писать?

Comment: если события только TCP и SSLLOG то так и напишите `(TCP|SSLLOG)` зачем делать шаблон таким сложно читаемым?

Comment: На счет дат - Вы правы, спасибо за корректировку.
На счет событий - нет, событий больше (>15 различных), эти взяты для примера.